# How do I (manually) intercept and return a custom message to a browser making a HTTPS request

Tags: ssl, https

I am creating a 'firewall' type device (i.e. sitting in the middle of a communication) that in some cases need to intercept a HTTPS request and return a message to the client browser (like e.g. : sorry this is blocked).

I can do this for HTTP by redirecting (with iptables DNAT) to another port on the device where netcat is listening:
while true; do echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\nsorry this is blocked"|nc -l -p 8000; done

(so nc is listening on port 8000 and returning a normal code 200 reply. Could of course also be some other return code like 403 Forbidden etc.)

But what to do for HTTPS? 
The whole thing is encapsulated in SSL/TLS and if intercepted the browser will just display a message that the secure connection failed.
I tried responding with a HTTP 307 Temporary Redirect with a Location pointing to http://127.0.0.1 (which would then give the above message). But the browser doesn't like this.

I need to display some sort of customized message (not necessarily HTML).
I realize that it would be a huge security issue if a HTTPS request could be changed to HTTP, thus stripping the security without the client noticing, but can a popup message or something not be forced in the client? Or at least a standard code like '403 Forbidden'..?
Is there something in the SSL or TLS protocols that I can (ab)use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are developing a transparent proxy. When it comes to HTTPS traffic every proxy has the choice:

- Pass it without decryption
- Block it completely
- Perform a man-in-the-middle attack for getting access to the content

If you performing the man-in-the-middle attack and the client does not trust the certificate used by the proxy it will get a certificate warning. You can not send anything HTTP related to the client because SSL/TLS already fails to establish the tunnel. No tunnel means that you will not be able to transmit a single "HTTP byte" (this also means that you can not redirect the client somewhere else).

And on SSL/TLS level there is AFAIK no way to send a custom message. The "TLS alert message" only allows [pre-defined constant values](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-69).